# It is possible for a Thread from ThreadPool to see a stale(processor cached) value?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, shared-memory

When using the .NET ThreadPool there is some guarantee that actions performed in a thread prior using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method happen-before its execution begins?

For example:

```
class MyClass {
  int my_var_;

  public void Start() {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Work);
  }

  public void Work() {
    my_var_ = 10;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Work2);
  }

  public void Work2(object obj) {
    my_var_ = 20;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Work3);
  }

  public void Work3(object obj) {
    Console.WriteLine(my_var_);
  }
}
```

Assuming that the same Thread that has been executed the Work method executes the Work3 method, it is possible that the value "10" is printed to the Console?

Comment: Yes; read about `volatile`.

Comment: volatile is all about ordering and not freshness.

Comment: Starting a thread and getting it running inevitably involves a memory barrier, required both by the ThreadPool and the operating system's thread scheduler to safely access their internal data structures.  So it is safe, by induction :)

Comment: @HansPassant Even when the Thread is reused a memory barrier is implicit involved?

Comment: Yes.  You do realize that you can never get a warranty here?  A custom CLR host can provide an alternative implementation both for Thread and ThreadPool.  The odds that you'll run into one are 1E-42.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using the .NET ThreadPool there is some guarantee that actions
>   performed in a thread prior using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
>   method happen-before its execution begins?

Yes. Like Hans already said any action that would cause code to execute in another thread will create a memory barrier on the initiator such that writes are committed and on the target such that reads are fresh. It would be terribly unfortunate for us if it did not work this way.

> Assuming that the same Thread that has been executed the Work method
>   executes the Work3 method, it is possible that the value "10" is
>   printed to the Console?

No. There is no execution path that leads to 10 being written to the console. In fact, there really is very little (or no) parallelism or interleaving of execution the way you currently have things setup. So `Console.WriteLine` must necessarily execute after the assignment `my_var_ = 20`. And since that write will be committed before `Work3` starts (potentially in another thread) the read will return the latest change.